# How to generate the seed value for a particular choice in a sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, random, random-seed

I have a list of these integers

List = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50 ,60, 70, 80, 90, 100]

How do I generate a seed value (a) to use with the Random.seed(a) module to get a particular result ( the number 70  in this case)?
I want to call the random.choice funcrion while passing the list argument. i.e random.choice(list). I need to set my seed to a particular value to get a result of 70.
And can I use seed values to generate particular results in non integer type lists, if so how?

Comment: I don't think this is remotely feasible unless you were using a custom, awful random number generator.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. `random.seed` always returns None, so you can't make it return 70. Or do you mean you're calling another function from  `random` after calling `random.seed`? Which one are you calling?

Comment: I want to call the random.choice funcrion while passing the list argument. i.e random.choice(list). I need to set my seed to a particular value to get a result of 70.

Answer (score 2):

by chance `0` as seed works (in my python implementation at least)...

```
from random import Random

List = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50 , 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]

rnd = Random(0)
ret = rnd.choice(List)
print(ret)  # 70
```

if that were not the case i'd just have tested (brute-forced) more seeds until the desired result had come up...

[`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) can be used on sequences of any type.

Answer (score 2):

you can use :

```
from random import Random

def get_seed(my_list, wanted_element):
    seed = 0
    while True:
        rnd = Random(seed)
        if rnd.choice(my_list) == wanted_element:
            return seed
        seed += 1
print(get_seed(List, 70)
```

output:

```
0
```

test:

```
rnd = Random(0)
print(rnd.choice(List)
# 70
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's what you meant, but using brute force:

```py
import random

def random_seed(List, number):
    s = 0
    while True:
        random.seed(s)
        if List[random.randint(0, len(List))] == number:
            return s
        s += 1


List = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50 ,60, 70, 80, 90, 100]

print("seed:", random_seed(List, 70))
```

Output:

```
seed: 0
```

Comment: Amusingly it fails for `List = [70]`, where *any* seed should be good.

Comment: This works,when the seed value is set to 0 i.e random.seed(0), the random.randint always results in 70 .  List[random.randint(0, len(List))] results in 70.           I also used the method to determine the seed values of other numbers in the list.Thank you.